# GCPのCloudRunのようなサービスが、AWS上に存在するか知りたい

Tags: aws

GCPのようにマネージド環境でかつ自由にDockerコンテナを扱えるAWS上のサービスが知りたいです。
昨年AWSのLambdaがコンテナをサポートしたと知ったのですが、Lamddaで代替え可能なのでしょうか。
クラウド初心者の質問なので、内容が曖昧で恐縮ですがどなたかご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

[AWS や Azure サービスと Google Cloud を比較する](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/aws-azure-gcp-service-comparison?hl=ja)によるとCloud Runに相当するサービスとして

- [AWS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/fargate/)
- [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/lambda/)
- [AWS App Runner](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/apprunner/)

があげられていました。
また、[AWS のコンテナ](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/containers/)ではコンテナ関連のサービスが一覧できます。

なんとなくですが、AWS App Runnerが希望に近いでしょうか？

Comment: ご連絡遅れてしまい、すみません！
sayuriさんの回答記事を拝見し、私も調べてみて、AppRunnnerが今の希望に近いことがわかりました。
ご教示いただきありがとうございました！